# Paypal adaptive payment chained "primary receiver" money fiscal

Tags: paypal, payment, marketplace, chained

I'm trying to figure out if the method chained wins the total of the money before doing the split,or if this method in tax collects only his part.
The difference is very large, it changes if cut out 100 or a tenth.
Thank you

Comment: Hi Silvio - If you're asking who takes a larger portion of the taxes; it would be the person who receives most of the $; but  the primary receiver determines how much each person gets when it's distributed. Here, you use this doc to help you understand chained payments better 8^) https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking who takes a larger portion of the taxes; it would be the person who receives most of the $; but  the primary receiver determines how much each person gets when it's distributed. Here, you use this doc to help you understand chained payments better 8^) https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/